# regex convert text to date

Tags: javascript, parsehub

I'm using parsehub to extract data. There is a date in the format `thursday 22 december 2022`
but I need it in a date string `dd/mm/yyyy`. Is there a way to do that with regex javascript?

I can't find info about a way to solve this.

Comment: I do not see what regex has to do with date parsing.

Answer (score 1):

You could solve it without `regex` using only `JavaScript`

1: Parse your string into a date

2: Extract and concatenate needed values using `JS` built-in date methods

```js
function formatDate(date) {
    function checkZero(num){return (num < 10)? '0'+num : num}

    let parsed = new Date(date);
    return `${checkZero(parsed.getDate())}/${checkZero(parsed.getMonth() + 1)}/${parsed.getFullYear()}`;
}
console.log('Case1: '+formatDate('Thursday 22 december 2022'));
console.log('Case2: '+formatDate('Monday 4 July 2022'));
```

Or simply, you can use this line of code

```
let foratedDate = new Date('Thursday 22 december 2022').toLocaleDateString('FR-fr');
```

Note: The 2 solutions return the same result but, the first one has more flexibility in formatting to many other shapes

Comment: This will have the result as '2/12/2022' for days and months which are less than 10.

Comment: @RahulTripathi You're right, code updated

Comment: `toLocaleDateString()` method are region dependant and not allways `dd/mm/yyyy` format!

Comment: @MisterJojo, It's my bad I put `getMonth()` instead of `getDate()`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it without regex as well

```js
function myDateFormat(date) {
    var d = new Date(date),
        month = '' + (d.getMonth() + 1),
        day = '' + d.getDate(),
        year = d.getFullYear();

    return [day, month, year].join('/');
}
 
console.log(myDateFormat('Thursday 22 december 2022'));
```

The above will not add '0' to the month and date so you need to add a condition to get the date and month as 'dd' and 'mm' instead of d and m.

```
if (month.length < 2) 
    month = '0' + month;
if (day.length < 2) 
    day = '0' + day;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply :
please note the addition of zeros on months, days when these are less than 10

```js
const strDate2dmy = dteStr => new Date(dteStr).toLocaleDateString('fr-FR');
 

console.log( strDate2dmy( 'Thursday 22 december 2022' ) )  // 22/12/2022
console.log( strDate2dmy( 'Monday 4 July 2022' ) )         // 04/07/2022
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the answers but that doesn't work with parsehub.

a alternative is to do it with PHP code.
Found a option in one of the plugins to work with custom php to change value of data.

https://www.wpallimport.com/documentation/inline-php/

any suggestions

Answer (score -2):

One hacky way is:

```js
new Date('thursday 22 december 2022').toJSON().slice(0, 10).split('-').reverse().join('/');
```

Result: `"22/12/2022"`

Or perhaps try this:

```js
new Date('thursday 22 december 2022').toLocaleDateString()
```

Comment: very bad answer! it doesn't take care of timezone offset!  also, toLocaleDateString() method are region dependant and not allways `dd/mm/yyyy` format!

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nope, I was the first to suggest `toLocaleDateString()`

Comment: @MisterJojo amazingly noticed. Sorry. Indeed. Upped!